# react set state callback correct way to pass an argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using React's `setState` method, and calling another function when the state has been updated.

Is there a preferred approach as to how to call the function that is passed to `setState` as a callback.

Both of the approaches below work but is there any performance implications of using one over the other?

```
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      result: '1-0'
    }
  }, this.clearResult(500))
```

or

```
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      result: '1-1',

    }
  }, () => this.clearResult(500))
```

My `clearPin` method looks like the following. All of this code is within a React component.

```
  clearResult(time) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        result: '0-0'
      })
    }, time)

  }
```

Comment: `clearResult` or `clearPin`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Both of the approaches below work but is there any performance implications of using one over the other?

There's a **correctness** implication: The first one is incorrect, the second one is correct. :-)

In your first example, you're calling `this.clearResult(500)` and **then** calling `setState` (with the result of calling `this.clearResult(500)` — `undefined`, in your example — as its second argument). `this.setState(prevState => { ... }, this.clearResult(500));` is just like `foo(bar())` — first it calls `bar`, then it passes the result of calling it into `foo`.

In your second example, you're passing a function into `setState` that it will call when the state is updated.

You want the second form (or one of the various equivalents to it).

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    result: '1-1',
  }
}, () => this.clearResult(500));
// or:  }, this.clearResult.bind(this, 500));
// But the arrow is clear and idiomatic
```

Here's proof that your first example is calling `clearResult` *before* calling `setState`, and before your state change callback is called:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {value: "a"};
  }
  
  // Overriding it PURELY to show what's happening
  setState(...args) {
    console.log("setState called");
    return super.setState(...args);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      () => {
        console.log("state change callback");
        return {value: "b"};
      },
      this.clearResult(500)
    );
  }
  
  clearResult(delay) {
    console.log("clearResult called");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({value: "c"});
    }, delay);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.value}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

whereas with `() => this.clearResult(500)` instead, `clearResult` is called after `setState` (and after the state change):

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {value: "a"};
  }
  
  // Overriding it PURELY to show what's happening
  setState(...args) {
    console.log("setState called");
    return super.setState(...args);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      () => {
        console.log("state change callback");
        return {value: "b"};
      },
      () => this.clearResult(500)
    );
  }
  
  clearResult(delay) {
    console.log("clearResult called");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({value: "c"});
    }, delay);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.value}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note 1: If you want, you can be a bit more concise:

```
this.setState(
    () => ({ result: '1-1' }),
    () => this.clearResult(500)
);
```

Side note 2: There's no need to use the function form if the new state you're passing **isn't** based on current state or props. In your example, it isn't, so yours is one of the places where using the non-callback form is okay:

```
this.setState(
    { result: '1-1' },
    () => this.clearResult(500)
);
```

That **would not** be okay if you were using something from `this.state` or `this.props`. In that situation, use the callback form and its `prevState` and `props` parameters. Always. And there's little harm in always using the callback form, the overhead of a function call is exceptionally trivial on modern JavaScript engines. (It was even trivial on the slowest JS engine of this century: The one in IE6.)

More on that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: if the first one is incorrect should it NOT work? :-S

Comment: @peterflanagan: It's working because it *happens* that `clearResult` is setting a timer and it *happens* that React is performing the state update before that timer fires. But it's still incorrect. :-) It introduces a race condition (and of course, in most cases you wouldn't be setting a timer at all, and so your "after done" would run before the state update even sttarted).

Comment: @peterflanagan: computers are fast. It just appears to work since you have timeout of 500ms. If you remove the timeout you will see that the functions are not invoked in the order you want.

Comment: @peterflanagan: A pleasure. :-) I've added two live-runnable examples to illustrate the call order. Happy coding!