# Callback prevent setState

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with a child component for a browse button, on the parent component, with a callback I set the state with the browsed file.

For some reason, because of a different callback passed to an higher parent component the state is not being set with the attached file.
If I remove the second callback `this.props.handleChange('attachment', file);` everything works fine. Any idea why? (Nothing is wrong with the second callback, no errors etc)

`Attachment` page:

```
export default class Attachment extends React.Component {
  state = {
    attachment: {},
  };

  handleAddAttachment = file => {
    this.setState({ attachment: file });
    this.props.handleChange('attachment', file); // this causes the previous line to not working.
  };

  render() {
    const { attachment } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div>
          <div>
            Do you have
            <br />
            something to <LineBreak />
            show me?
          </div>
          <div css={attach}>Upload attachments here</div>
          <AttachmentButton  handleAddAttachment={this.handleAddAttachment} />
          <AttachedFile attachment={attachment} />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

`makeHandleChange` method on parent component:

```
  makeHandleChange = (pageName, change) => {
    this.setState({
      ticket: { ...this.state.ticket, [pageName]: change },
    });
  };
```

Comment: why don't you let the parent control the attached file through state and pass it to the child as prop?

Comment: What does this.props.handleChange do? What is its context?

Comment: @user3378165 see my answer below.

Comment: @Avanthika, I added to the question the invocation method of `this.props.handleChange`

Comment: please share your parent code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because your parent component gets new state so it rerenders and also causes the children to rerender and cancel the state. To keep your children intact you can set a key props to your child component or you can use shouldComponentUpdate. like this in your parent

```
<Attachment key="attachment-key" />
```

Comment: Absolutely, I posted from phone so was not able to add. I will fix that

Comment: can you share a sandbox to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this doesn't work, but you may want to try a workaround: passing the function as the second argument to setState.

See an example here:
[react set state callback correct way to pass an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667136/react-set-state-callback-correct-way-to-pass-an-argument/48667192#48667192)

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know the context of what `this.props.handleChange()` does, I'm giving a generic answer. Try changing the function this way:

```
  handleAddAttachment = file => {
    this.setState({
      attachment: file 
    }, () => {
       this.props.handleChange('attachment', file);
    });  
  };
```